# Angular Activated Route get Params - Not Working

Tags: angular, routes

Im trying to get angular params OnINit but nothing seems to work, I truies Params, ParaMap, QueryParamap, below is my implementation:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" [routerLink]="['/page/office', item._id]">Edit Page</a>
```

Router.ts:

```
{ path: 'page', component: pageComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'office/:id', component: OfficeComponent },
    ]
}
```

Component Logic:

```
this._activatedRoute.paramMap
.subscribe( (params: ParamMap) => {
        this.page_id = params.get('id')
        console.log(params);
});
```

I wonder what im doing  wrong here or I missed implementing? I tried Params, queryParams I get null value. where in my link has http://localhost:4200/page/office/5efca7d6d4bcee10c13b2562

Comment: Hi, http://localhost:4200/page/office/5efca7d6d4bcee10c13b2562 it is your local url, that we cannot get this url

Comment: Yes I know Im just give you the url structure which I have to get params

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use firstChild property of `ActivatedRoute`

```
this._activatedRoute.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {
   this.page_id = params['id'];
   console.log(params);
});
```

Comment: can you explain firstChild? Is it because I have Children routes ?? This does worked thanx mate been struggling this for half an hour

Comment: You are using child parent architecture in router config. And you have only one child inside this parent route. So need to send request to child of parent.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation mate

Answer (score 0):

```
this._activatedRoute.paramMap
.subscribe( (params) => {
        this.page_id = params['id']
        console.log(params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your params `ActivatedRoute` snapshot. like this

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params
```

Comment: No mate this is dynamic and it will change eventually thats why using subscribe, also this gived me undefined too

Answer (score 0):

Because your passed tenant value, so you must be use **ActivatedRoute** snapshot. like this

```
let _value = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
```

> Use it on the constructor() or ngOnInit() methods